# Hudson Error Message: Admin user is missing Administer permission

Tags: continuous-integration, hudson

I'm getting an error message in Hudson when I try to access the configuration page saying:

> Admin user is missing Administer permission

I'm not aware of any changes in the configuration since it last worked. In the config.xml file the admin user appears to be set up correctly:

```
<permission>hudson.model.Hudson.Administer:admin</permission>
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by [disabling security in Hudson](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Disable+security), then enabling security through the UI and setting up access control settings for the admin user again.